# VBA плохая неполная документация

Tags: vba, библиотеки, документация

У VBA есть куча библиотек. Под базовые библиотеки у них есть полноценная официальная документация (описание что делает, какие-то детали, примеры). Это, например, Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library. А под другие библиотеки (например, Microsoft HTML Object Libary) официальной полноценной документации нет. И это меня возмущает.

Без официальной полноценной документации изучаются библиотеки крайне медленно. После Python изучение VBA выглядит ужасным. Приходится гуглить с целью поиска примеров-скриптов, решающих мою проблему. Библиотеки так изучаются медленно и ограниченно.

1. Т.к. я новичок в VBA, то хотел спросить действительно все так плохо с VBA, как я описываю? Почему так сложилось?
2. Какой самый эффективный путь изучения библиотек, по которым нет документации? Только чужие скрипты или что-то еще?

Comment: Эффективнее всего записать макрос. И где непонятно смотреть свойства через команду SET

Comment: Конкретно по VBA в офисном пакете обычно самый простой способ -- это кликнуть "записать макрос", кликнуть нужное действие, остановить запись и посмотреть на сгенерированный код. В целом по библиотекам -- гитхаб и изучение чужих проектов, изучение исходников (в том числе -- и декомпилированных самостоятельно), вопросы коллегам, которые уже осваивали её. Но в целом программисты потому и любят доки и исходники, потому что это ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО облегчает вхождение в проект.

Answer (score 1):

Майкрософт в основном перешел на платформу `.NET`. В VBA эта платформа также доступна. Открывайте справку по C# и смотрите описание библиотек с поправкой на синтаксик. Имена функций и семантика одна и та же.

Comment: Microsoft HTML Object Libary (VBA). Как документацию по этой библиотеке найти? Скиньте ссылку пожалуйста. Я совсем новичок. Я ваш ответ не понимаю. Я думал, что C# кардинально различается по составу и содержимому библиотек от VBA. Получается, что библиотеки C# переводили на язык VBA. Что-то в голове не укладывается.

Comment: Тык там все просто. Помню, ещё 15 лет назад было: нажал "записать макрос", потом остановил. Открыл редактор кода, смотришь, что сгенерировалось и так постепенно изучаешь. Лучше любых мануалов. Вба может немного посложнее питона, ибо он априори является строго типизированные языком. Но этим же он и проще. Просто надо поймать волну

Comment: @Александр так хттп запрос не сделать из макроса..

Comment: @eri, ну почему ж.  http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-basic/thread69792.html.  Можно подключить сторонние библиотеки, либо использовать винайпи для работы с сетью. Это не просто, но возможно сделать. Но лично для меня это не особо удобно

Comment: @Александр имею ввиду через "меню - запись макроса" такую справку не получишь

Comment: @eri, впрочем верно. Но тем не менее, это мне не кажется сложным. Первая ссылка в Гугле дала ответ на русском языке с избытком примеров..

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш комментарий не отвечает на мои конкретные вопросы.